# How to access the function on outer Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-html5

I cant call method() inside FB.api. how can I access method?
 cant do it this.method(); or method();

```
var MyLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
   init: function(){
      FB.init({
       ............
      });
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  this.method(); // <---- I cant call this here. How can I call method(); ?? Thank!
               });
         }
      });
   },
   method: function(){
      alert("Hello");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Save a reference to `this` and use that:

```
var MyLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
   init: function(){
       var that = this; // Save reference to context
       //.....
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  that.method(); // Call method on stored context
               });
           }
        });
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callback functions to the context (requires ES5):

```
var MyLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
   init: function(){
       //.....
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
           if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  this.method(); // Call method on context
               }.bind(this)); // Bind callback to context
           }
        }.bind(this)); // Bind callback to context
    }
});
```

Comment: Came here for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var MyLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
   init: function(){
      FB.init({});
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.status === 'connected') {
               FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                  MyLayer.method(); 
               });
         }
      });
   },
   method: function(){
      alert("Hello");
   }
});
```